# RXJS and typescript: Conditionally executing work with Server and Client Code

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, rxjs, conditional-statements

My requirement is to provide a function that uses various conditions to determine whether an object can be edited.

These conditions can be on both the server and the client side.
Some of these conditions should abort the execution of further validation and return the value.

i will try to make the process understandable with pseudo code.
Perhaps there is already a pattern for implementing such tasks.

```js
isEditable(): Observable<boolean> {
  return serverSideCondition.pipe(
    switchMap(editable => {
      if (editable)
      {
        return clientSideCondition;
      }

      return of(false); // Should abort furhter conditions ...
    }),
    switchMap(editable => {
      if (editable)
      {
        return clientSideAskTheUser;
      }

      return of(false); // Should abort furhter conditions ...
    })
  );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what wrong with your code?

Comment: you can try iif operator, https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an error and catch it later on if you don't want to pass a `false` value through all operators.

````ts
isEditable(): Observable<boolean> {
  return serverSideCondition.pipe(
    throwIfFalsy(),
    switchMap(editable => clientSideCondition.pipe(throwIfFalsy())),   
    switchMap(editable => clientSideAskTheUser.pipe(throwIfFalsy())),
    // other operators ...
    catchError(error => of(error))
  );
}

throwIfFalsy() {
  return tap(value => {
    if (!value) {
      throw value
    }
  })
}
```
````